# Workaround to Post in a friend wall after Graph API feature is deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My iOS app is trying to post to a friend's timeline. I was using the Graph API, but it's seems from what I read at [Platform Updates: Operation Developer Love of February](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) that is now deprecated and you can't post on a friends wall using that. Without this feature the social part of my app will be very weak. So, I did some research and found that using some deprecated headers you still can publish on a friends feed (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/). After doing all the code, I'm just missing a small part that I can't found anywhere that is how can I set a default text to this Facebook Dialog? Or if someone has another way to do it without using these deprecated stuff please share...

Thanks

```
// Put together the dialog parameters
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               friendID,@"to",
                               @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
                               @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                               @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
                               @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
                               nil];

// Invoke the dialog
[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```